# Finding Class Elements in a List of Classes

Tags: c#, list, find

I am trying to use the "List.Find" method to find a match with an element in my class.  Here is an example...

```
class MyClass
{
    String item1;
    String item2;
}

List<MyClass> myClassList = new List<MyClass>();

// I am trying to find all instances of "MyClass" in the list "myClassList"
// where the element "item1" is equal to "abc"
// myClassList.Find(item => .item1 == "abc"); ?????
```

Anyway, I hope that explains a bit better.  I am confused about the last part, so my question is: How can I use List.Find to find matches of an element in a list of classes.

Thanks and please let me know if I'm not being clear.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your example is almost there. You should probably be using the [`FindAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh1w7y8z.aspx) method:

```
List<MyClass> results = myClassList.FindAll(x => x.item1 == "abc");
```

Or, if you prefer your results to be typed as `IEnumerable<T>` rather than `List<T>`, you can use LINQ's [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where.aspx) method:

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> results = myClassList.Where(x => x.item1 == "abc");
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) extension method:

```
var items = myClassList.Where(x => x.item1 == "abc");
```

The above snippet will return all objects with property `item1` equal to "abc".